# Export icon individually from the react icon package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, rollup

I have created a icon package and publishing the package with name as @rct/icons.

My package.json is as below

```
{
  "name": "@rct/icons",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  "prebuild": "rimraf src && rimraf dist",
  "build": "npm run svgr && rollup -c",
  "svgr": "svgr --icon --title-prop --replace-attr-values '#1D1D1D=currentColor' -d src -- 
    assets"
 }
}
```

I am using [svgr](https://react-svgr.com/) to convert svg to react components and icons are exported in index.js by svgr as below

```
export { default as HeartFilled } from './HeartFilled';
export { default as LikeFilled } from './LikeFilled';
```

Currently, the `@rct/icons` package is getting installed completely and the import should be done as below on the consumer side;

```
import { LikeFilled, HeartFilled } from '@rct/icons';
```

How to export each icons individually as `@rct/icons/LikeFilled` and import in another react app as below;

```
import { LikeFilled } from '@rct/icons/LikeFilled';
```

Please check the below stackblitz url for implementation;
https://react-ajs15h.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import from the icon directly as a named export, then just update the exports in your icon files to look something like:

```
export { SvgComponent as LikeFilled }
```

As for [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/), it looks like it has a ['named export' feature](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?exportType=named) (maybe it didn't when you asked this? Just surprised no one answered)